Unable to click on element using Selenium Python
I am trying to scrape conference websites from this list of conferences: https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/en/meetings/archive/#2022
This requires Selenium to click on 'Details' to get to the website. Unfortunately, my code hasn't been able to work.
The following is what I've tried:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Setup Chrome WebDriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get("https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/en/meetings/archive/#2022")

# Wait for the element to be clickable
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="archive_meetings_list"]/li/div/div/details/summary')))

# Click the "Details" summary element
details_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="archive_meetings_list"]/li/div/div/details/summary')
details_button.click()


However, I get a TimeOutException as selenium cannot find the element specified by the XPATH.

The list of conference websites is populated on the page by an API call to https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/meetings/meetings?year=2022
If you want the data for each of the "Details" sections, you can just use:
import requests

url_base = 'https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/meetings/meetings?year='
conference_info = []
sess = requests.Session()
for year in range(2015, 2025):
    res = sess.get(f'{url_base}{year}')
    conf_list = res.json()
    conference_info.extend(conf_list)

The resulting data looks like:
[
    {
        "address": "",
        "keywords": "Observacional, Astronomia, Astronomy, Escuela, Astronomy School",
        "start": "2015-01-11",
        "web2": "",
        "web1": "http://www.astroscu.unam.mx/cursos/esaobela/",
        "title": "Escuela de Astronomía Observacional para Estudiantes Latinoamericanos.",
        "meetingNumber": "4414",
        "ingested": "Jun 24, 2014 06:26:00 AM",
        "phone": "",
        "contact": "Jose H. Peña",
        "modified": "Jun 24, 2014 06:26:00 AM",
        "location": "Tonantzintla, Puebla. México.",
        "end": "2015-01-30",
        "fax": "",
        "bibCode": "",
        "email": __removed__
    },
    {
        "address": "Centre for Theoretical Atomic, Molecular and Optical Physics (CTAMOP) School of Mathematics and Physics Queens University Belfast David Bates Bldg, Room  01.016 7 College Park Belfast BT7 1NN, UK",
        "keywords": "quantitative spectroscopy, emission lines, Active Nuclei, Starburst galaxies, H II regions, star formation",
        "start": "2015-01-12",
        "web2": "",
        "web1": "http://cloud9.pa.uky.edu/~gary/cloudy/CloudySummerSchool/",
        "title": "Cloudy workshop 2015 Jan 12-16 at Queen's University Belfast",
        "meetingNumber": "4440",
        "ingested": "Aug 03, 2014 10:13:00 AM",
        "phone": "",
        "contact": "Gary Ferland",
        "modified": "Aug 03, 2014 10:13:00 AM",
        "location": "Queen's University Belfast, NI, UK",
        "end": "2015-01-16",
        "fax": "",
        "bibCode": "",
        "email": __removed__
    },
   ...


Ahh I see, this worked perfectly! Thanks!
